# Order confirmation email send twice for customer Magento 2.4

Tags: magento, magento2

When a customer has placed a new order the customer receives two duplicate confirmation emails.

How can I solve it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @mrwho Have you seen my answer? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: If you are creating an order from admin, please check out if patch [ACSD-46146](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/support-tools/patches/acsd-46146-two-order-confirmation-emails-are-sent-after-placing-order-from-admin.html?lang=en) might solve the issue.

==========

This might look like the confirmation is sent twice. But probably the first mail is the order confirmation and the second one the invoice. These mails look really similar with default Magento.

You can check this settings under Stores > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails. If both Order > Enabled and Invoice > Enables are set to Yes, the customer will receive two almost similar mails when an order is placed and directly invoiced.

You can consider to only enable the confirmation mail.